# Parsing JSON then adding multiple strings to an ArrayList

Tags: android, json, parsing, rest

Currently working on an app that takes results from a search, parses the JSON object returned, and then adds the resulting pieces into a few `ArrayLists` within a class created called `VenueList`.

Here is the method that receives the results from the service and parses the JSON:

```
 private static List<String> getResultsFromJson(String json) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();         
    try {
        JSONObject resultsWrapper = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue(); 
        JSONArray  results        = resultsWrapper.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
            resultList.add(result.getString("text")); 

        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON.", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

What results of this becomes a `List` variable call `mResults` (to clarify: `mResults = getResultsFromJson(restResult);`.  That is then used, among other places, in the following loop that puts the results into an `ArrayAdapter` that is used for displaying them in a ListFragment:

```
for (String result : mResults) {    
    VenueList.addVenue(result, "HELLO WORLD"); 
    adapter.add(result);
}
```

I also add the result to a class called `VenueList` that manages the results and makes them accessible for multiple views.  It essentially just holds multiple `ArrayLists` that hold different types of details for each venue returned in the search.  The method I use to add a venue to `VenueList` is below (and you can see it used in the for loop above):

```
public static void addVenue(String name, String geo) {
    venueNames.add(name);
    venueGeos.add(geo);
}
```

I want the `addVenue` method to be able to take multiple arguments and update the `VenueList` class.  Yet, when I call the `addVenue` method in the for loop, I can only pass it `String result` (from the parameters of the loop) and can't figure out how to pass it a second argument (which should also come from the JSON parsed by `getResultsFromJson`) so I've used `"HELLO WORLD"` as a placeholder for now.

I realize `getResultsFromJson` only has one list returned.  I need to be able to take multiple elements from the JSON object that I parse, and then add them to VenueList in the right order.

So my questions are:

1) Given the `getResultsFromJson` method and the `for` loop, how can I use the `addVenue()` method as designed?  How do I parse multiple elements from the JSON, and then add them to the VenueList at the same time?  I plan on adding more arguments to it later on, but I assume if I can make it work with two, I can make it work with four or five.

2) If that's not possible, how should the `getResultsFromJson`, the `for` loop, and the `addVenue` method be redesigned to work properly together?

Please let me know if you need more detail or code - happy to provide.  Thank you!

EDIT - Full VenueList class:

```
public class VenueList {

private static ArrayList<String> venueNames; 
private static ArrayList<String> venueGeos;

public VenueList() {
    venueNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    venueGeos = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public static void addVenue(String name, String geo) { 
    venueNames.add(name);
    venueGeos.add(geo);
}

public static String getVenueName(int position) { 
    return venueNames.get(position);
}

public static String getVenueGeo(int position) {
    return venueGeos.get(position);
}

public static void clearList() {
    venueNames.clear();
    venueGeos.clear();
}

}
```

Clarification: I will have additional ArrayLists for each element of data that I want to store about a venue (phone number, address, etc etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I don't think methods getResultsFromJson(String json) and addVenue(String name, String geo) fit your needs.

2) I would consider rewriting method getResultsFromJson(String json) to something like this:

```
private static SortedMap<Integer, List<String>> getResultsFromJson(String json) {
    Map<Integer, String> resultMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();         

    //...

    return resultMap;
}
```

where the number of keys of your map should be equal to the number of objects you're extracting info, and each one of them will properly have their own list of items just in the right order you extract them.

With this approach you can certainly change your logic to something like this:

```
// grab your retuned map and get an entrySet, the just iterate trough it
SortedMap<Integer, String> result = returnedMap.entrySet();

for (Entry<Integer, String> result : entrySet) {    
    Integer key = result.getKey(); // use it if you need it
    List<String> yourDesiredItems = result.getValue(); // explicitly shown to know how to get it

    VenueList.addVenue(yourDesiredItems); 
}

public static void addVenue(List<String> yourDesiredItems) {
    // refactor here to iterate the items trough the list and save properly    

    //....
}
```

**EDIT -- as you wish to avoid the go-between map i'm assuming you need nothing to return from the method**

First i'm providing you with a solution to your requirements, then i'll provide you with some tips cause i see some things that could smplify your design.

To save VenueList things directly from `getResultsFromJSON` do something like this:

```
private static void getResultsFromJson(String json) {
    try {
        JSONObject resultsWrapper = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue(); 
        JSONArray  results        = resultsWrapper.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);

            //FOR EXAMPLE HERE IS WHERE YOU NEED TO EXTRACT INFO
            String name = result.getString("name");
            String geo = result.getString("geo");

            // and then...

            VenueList.addVenue(name, geo, ..., etc);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON.", e);
    }
}
```

This implies that your `addVenue` method should know receive all params needed; as you can see this is just a way (that you can consider a workaround to your needs), however as i don't know all requirements that lead you to code this model, i will point to a few things you might consider:

***1.*** *If there's a reason for `VenueList` class to use everything static, consider doing this:*

```
static{
    venueNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    venueGeos = new ArrayList<String>();
    //....
}

private VenueList(){
}
```

This way you won't need to get an instance every time and also will avoid `null pointer exceptions` when doing `VenueList.addVenue(...)` without previous instantiation.

***2.*** *Instead of having an `ArrayList` for every characteristic in `VenueList` class consider defining a `model object` for a `Venue` like this:*

```
public class Venue{
    String name;
    String geo;
    //... etc

    public Venue(){
    }

    // ... getters & setters
}
```

then if you need that `VenueList` class you will just have a list o Venue objects `(List<Venue>)`, this means that instead of calling the method `addVenue`, you will first create a brand new instance of `Venue` class and will call the setter method of each characteristic, as an example of the refactored for loop from the workaround i provided you you'd be using something like this:

```
List<Venue> myListOfVenues = new ArrayList<Venue>();

for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);

    // THIS WOULD REMAIN THE SAME TO EXTRACT INFO
    String name = result.getString("name");
    String geo = result.getString("geo");

    // and then instead of calling VenueList.addVenue(name, geo, ..., etc)...
    Venue v = new Venue();
    v.setName(name);
    v.setGeo(geo);
    // ...etc

    myListOfVenues.add(v);
}

// Once you're done, set that List to VenueList class
VenueList.setVenueList(myListOfVenues);
```

So `VenueList` class would now have a single property `List<Venue> venueList;` and would suffer minor tweeks on methods `getVenueName, etc...` and everything would be more readable... i hope this helps you to get another approach to solve your problem, if i still don't make my point let me know and i'll try to help you out...

Comment: Thank you.  Would there be a way to save to VenueList in getResultsFromJson rather than using the Maps as the go-between?

Comment: You can certainly do it refactoring the  `for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {  
    JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);  
    resultList.add(result.getString("text"));  }`  on your getResultsFromJSON method, then you can change the addVenue signature to accept all the params you need to set a once or simply use setter methods of your VenueListClass, provide more info about VenueList class, so i can help you better, if i'm not clear let me know so i can post an example as an update to my answer.

Comment: i think that makes sense, but im pretty new to this stuff so an example would be really helpful and greatly appreciate.  i think it would be better to avoid the maps, as they do just seem like a go-between, right?  i've posted to full VenueList class in the original message.

Comment: i've posted a new edit to show how you can avoid the maps as the go-between (consider that this is possible as long as you don't need that map somewhere else), hope it clarifies, if not... let me know, i'm glad to help...

Comment: this is fantastic help.  i don't have the time to implement today, but will try to tomorrow.  i will get back to you if there's an issue.  but honestly, this is the most thorough response i've ever received on SO, so i really appreciate it.

Comment: you're welcome... after you implement it if everything goes ok and you consider this was useful, please upvote and take it as the correct answer... regards

Comment: this was incredibly useful, just implemented it and it works properly.  i'm foreseeing one potential stumble, which is that my listview of results displays a single piece of data currently, but i will want it to display four or five of the items that end up in VenueList for each of the results.  Do you know how I can adapt the ArrayAdapter I'm using to fill my results ListView so that it can pass more than one piece of data?  I realize this might be vague/unclear, so let me know if I can provide more info/code.  Again, thank you so so so much for your help!

Comment: `my listview of results displays a single piece of data`, why? you need it to display all of the items that ended up in VenuList right? can you provide code of your ArrayAdapter so i can have a better understand of your need?? cheers!

Comment: what i mean is that for each result in the list, it only shows one attribute - venue name.  i need it to show multiple characteristics from VenueList for each result (i.e. name, phone number, etc).  i did a little research and figured out i can just send everything as a string, and then break it up in listview.  is that accurate?  my arrayadapter is just the default android array adapter: `mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_label_list);`

Comment: i don't think that's accurate, not even possible (if you know how to,  show me, it's always good to learn something every day), instead you should `create your own adapter extending from ArrayAdapter`, `provide your own layout` and `pass your List of Venue objects in its constructor`, you can do all the logic you want in there... if you've figured out something post it and i can point you to a better approach if needed...